# In Jupyter Notebook, how can the coloring of error output in the code snippets help me figure out the error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, syntax-error, jupyter-notebook

The screenshot below shows 3 lines of code in a Jupyter cell and the error output below it. I'd like to know if the differences between the error output for lines 4, 5, and 6 is meaningful and useful in troubleshooting the cause of the errors.

[image]

**Line 4**
 - `[adult_df['workclass'] == '?']` is all black

**Line 5**
 - The brackets and `==` are brown
 - Strings and quote marks are blue

**Line 6**
 - Everything, including closing parenthesis, is brown

Does the coloring hold clues that point to issues? Can the coloring help me figure out the error in my code? If so I would love to learn how.

I'm using

`Jupyter version 5.0.0-f6790e4 
Running on Python 3.6.4
MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)
IPython 6.2.1`

Comment: Neat coloring, but I think it is just some progressive fadeout. The really  meaningful part is the error message.

Comment: Also, does your dataframe have 3 dimensions?

Comment: Dataframe has 2 dimensions.

Comment: Why does a call have three arguements?

Comment: Short answer: I'm learning. I'm trying to display the rows that meet the condition. This works for one column: `adult_df[adult_df['age'] > 70]`. I can view multiple cols: `adult_df[['workclass', 'occupation', 'native_country']]`. Here's the count of instances of a condition on three cols: `((adult_df.workclass == " ").sum(), (adult_df.occupation == " ").sum(), (adult_df.native_country == " ").sum())`. So I tried combining the syntax. But this fails to show two columns with a condition on each: `adult_df[adult_df['age'] > 70], [adult_df['sex'] == 'Female']`. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you looking for `&` and `|`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Comment: Maybe. How would you write that? I tried these and got errors: `adult_df[adult_df['age'] > 70] | [adult_df['sex'] == 'Female']` # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list';
`adult_df[[adult_df['age'] > 70] | [adult_df['sex'] == 'Female']]` # ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 15: given 1;
`adult_df[adult_df['age'] > 70] | adult_df[adult_df['sex'] == 'Female']` # ValueError.